# Groupby in pandas, filling in missing groups with []

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Any help on a more precise title to this question is welcome..

I have a `pandas` dataframe with customer-level observations that records a date, and items consumed by the customer on that date. It looks like this.

```
df
store    day   items
 a        1     4
 a        1     3
 a        2     1
 a        3     5
 a        4     2 
 a        5     9
 b        1     1 
 b        2     3
```

Each observation in this data set pertains to a unique store-day combination, BUT each store-day observation is listed conditional on a positive number of items consumed, i.e. `df[items] > 0` for every store-day pair.

So I do not have, for example

```
b         3      0
b         4      0 
b         5      0
```

etc.

I need to group this dataframe by `store` and `day`, and then run some operations on all obs in each store-day group.

But, I want these lines to exist and with 0 length (null sets), and I am not sure the best way to do this.  This is a very simple toy dataset. The real one is very large.

I don't really want to add in the observations BEFORE using `df.groupby(['store', 'day'])`, because 
I run OTHER calculations on each store-day group that uses the length of each group as a measure of number of customers recorded in a specific store and day. Thus, if I add in those observations `b3` and `b4`, then it looks like there were 2 customers who visited the store b on days 3 and 4 - when there were not (each bought nothing at store b on days 3 and 4).

Answer (score 1):

You may already have answer to your question, in case someone else, like me, is looking for an answer. Try:

```
pd.crosstab(df.store, df.day, margins=False)
```

This will give you df with store as index and day as column. you can do something like:

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

to convert the index to a column and if you have multi index columns, something like:

```
df.columns = [''.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
```

to get a "flat" df.

You can do this:

```
pd.crosstab([df.store, df.day.....], [df.store, df.day.....],margins=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the best way to store the zero values, but you can create them when aggregating:

```
df.pivot_table('items', 'store', 'day', fill_value=0, aggfunc='count')
```

or

```
df.groupby(['store', 'day']).count().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'pandas' way of representing those would probably be to code it as missing data, like:

```
In [562]: df
Out[562]: 
  store  day  items
0     a    1      4
1     a    1      3
2     a    2      1
3     a    3      5
4     a    4      2
5     a    5      9
6     b    1      1
7     b    2      3
8     b    3    NaN
9     b    4    NaN
```

Then, in your aggregation to count customers, you could use `count` which excludes missing values, for example:

```
In [565]: df.groupby('store')['items'].count()
Out[565]: 
store
a        6
b        2
Name: items, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

In terms of adding missing values, here a couple thoughts.  Say you have a DataFrame that contains just the missing pairs, like this:

```
In [571]: df_missing
Out[571]: 
  store  day
8     b    3
9     b    4
```

Then you could just append these to your existing DataFrame to fill the missing, like this:

```
In [574]: pd.concat([df, df_missing], ignore_index=True)
Out[574]: 
   day  items store
0    1      4     a
1    1      3     a
2    2      1     a
3    3      5     a
4    4      2     a
5    5      9     a
6    1      1     b
7    2      3     b
8    3    NaN     b
9    4    NaN     b
```

Alternatively, if you a DataFrame with the pairs you 'should' have, (a 1-5, b 1-4), you could merge that against the data to fill the missing.  For example:

```
In [577]: df_pairs
Out[577]: 
  store  day
0     a    1
1     a    1
2     a    2
3     a    3
4     a    4
5     a    5
6     b    1
7     b    2
8     b    3
9     b    4

In [578]: df_pairs.merge(df, how='left')
Out[578]: 
   store  day  items
0      a    1      4
1      a    1      3
2      a    1      4
3      a    1      3
4      a    2      1
5      a    3      5
6      a    4      2
7      a    5      9
8      b    1      1
9      b    2      3
10     b    3    NaN
11     b    4    NaN
```

Comment: The data is much more complicated (lots of days and lots of stores), do you know how I can add in the missing observations easily?

Comment: See edit for how you could handle a couple situations.

Comment: How can I create df_pairs from the original dataset?

Comment: It'd require some knowledge of what the pairs should be.  For your example you could use `product` from `itertools` like this: `df_pairs = pd.DataFrame(list(product('a', range(1,6))) + list(product('b', range(1,5))), columns=['store', 'day'])`

Comment: Hm, that gives me TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type